# Swift_TransportException(503) - Expected response code 354 but got code "503", with message "503 5.5.1 Bad sequence of commands - Laravel

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

I am using Office 365 setting for sending my project's promotional email marketing. My mail sender email address is registered with office365 and I used SMPT settings with office365. When I send email with fewer recipient's email addresses there are no error. But when I try to send email to all my customer more than 3000 recipients, I got this error.

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eQhM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting the rate limit of **Exchange Limit** which is 30 message per minute. For more information please see this: [Exchange Sending limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#sending-limits-1)

By the way office 365, Gmail or other services like this are not suitable for bulk operations. Try using other services like AWS SES, Mailgun and etc.